# How to enable 'playback follows cursor' / 'skip silence' in itunes?

Tags: itunes, foobar2000

[foobar2000](http://www.foobar2000.org/) on Windows has got two pretty simple, yet very useful features (at least for me) that iTunes seems to be lacking:

- **Playback follows cursor**: Playback continues at the selected track
- **Skip silence**: foobar skips the silence in those 25 minute songs with 20 minutes of silence and a hidden track at the end.

Does iTunes support either of these features? And, if so, how do I enable them?

Comment: Operating system?

Comment: that would be Windows